# Find all $x$ for which $\left| x - \left| x-1 \right| \right| = \lfloor x \rfloor$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find all $x$ for which
$$\left| x - \left| x-1 \right| \right| = \lfloor x \rfloor.$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: One hint: for $x \ge 1$, you have $|x-|x-1|| = (x-(x-1))$

Comment: Hint: look at the $x \lt 1$, $x \ge 1$ cases separately.

Comment: @dxiv,it is not true $x<1$,since $x$ should be positive

Comment: @haqnatural $0<x<1$ then.  But still no biggie.

Comment: @haqnatural Of course $x \lt 1$ is a case that must be considered. In fact, if you check the posted answers, one of the solutions falls in that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{cancel}x=1$ can trivially be seen to work already.

if $x>1$:

$$|x-|x-1||=|x-(x-1)|=|1|=1=\lfloor x\rfloor\implies1<x<2$$

Assume $x\le1/2$:

$$|x-|x-1||=|x+(x-1)|=|2x-1|=2x-1=\lfloor x\rfloor\implies x=1/2,\xcancel1$$

Assume $1/2<x<1$:

$$|x-|x-1||=|x+(x-1)|=|2x-1|=1-2x=\lfloor x\rfloor\implies x=1/2$$

> Solutions are $x=1/2,1\le x<2$

You can trivially check for the cases $x<1$ using the knowledge that $|2x-1|$ must be a whole number.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by considering graphs of both sides, which will lead to the solution set $$x=\frac 12 \cup 1\leq x<2$$

The function on the left comprises a horizontal line $y=1$ for $x\geq 1$, and for $x\leq 1 $ you have a V shaped graph which is $y=|2x-1|$

You can see easily where this graph coincides with the floor function on the right